# Append data to txt file in Swift 3

Tags: ios, csv, text, swift3, append

Basically, I am trying to do this with Swift 3:

```
write a titleString to file
For i=1 to n
    newString = createNewString()  //these may look like "1: a, b, c"
    append each new string to end of file
next i
```

Here is what I have done:

```
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: completePath)
let titleString = "Line, Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"
var dataString: String
let list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let list3 = ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]


for i in 0...4 {
    dataString =  String(list1[i]) + ": " + list2[i] + list3[i] + "\n"

    //Check if file exists
    if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: fileURL.absoluteString) {
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
        fileHandle.write(dataString.data(using: .utf8)!)
    } else { //create new file

        do {
            try titleString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error creating file \(error)")
        }

    }
    print(dataString)
    print("Saving data in: \(fileURL.path)")
}
```

All I get in the file is the titleString.  The other strings don't show up.

Comment: Please use `if let fileHandle = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: fileURL)` in place of `if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: fileURL.absoluteString)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `FileHandle` for appending the existing file after checking if the file already exists.

```
let titleString = "Line, Item 1, Item 2, Item 3"
var dataString: String
let list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let list3 = ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]

do {
    try "\(titleString)\n".write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

for i in 0...4 {
    dataString =  String(list1[i]) + ": " + list2[i] + list3[i] + "\n"
    //Check if file exists
    do {
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.write(dataString.data(using: .utf8)!)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
    } catch {
        print("Error writing to file \(error)")
    }
    print(dataString)
    print("Saving data in: \(fileURL.path)")
}
```

Output:

```
Line, Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
1: ap
2: bq
3: cr
4: ds
5: et
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the file handle after writing.

Comment: There is no "Post Your Answer" box at the bottom to show what I did and not enough characters here...  But this didn't work either.

Comment: You should edit your original question if you have more to add on the issue. And please specify what you mean by "this didn't work either". What was the issue?

Comment: Oh, does being marked a duplicate prevent me from further discussing and posting what I did?

Comment: Thanks!  I edited above.

Comment: @Greg it seems like you're using the version of my answer before editing it.  You should also include the `fileHandle.closeFile()` line.

Comment: No, there are a few modifications.  For example, I used dataString if the file exists and titleString  when creating a new file.  And put it in the loop - is that the right place?

Comment: Yeah, all the other changes should be fine, but closing the file is necessary.

Comment: I've tried closing it at the very end as well as in the loop after the fileHandle.write(dataString.data(using: .utf8)!) line.  In both cases, the file contains only the titleString.
It's driving me nuts!  I miss good old C.....

Comment: Check my updated answer, I tested it and it's working fine now.

Comment: That does the trick!  Thank you Dávid!

Comment: I upvoted but my rep is too low to display :-(

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Even with a low reputation, you can accept an answer if you found it useful using the checkmark symbol under the downvoting arrow.

Comment: Great!  I'm still new to this stackoverflow...  Thanks again!